# Parallels, Mac and windows using US International keyboard

Tags: keyboard, parallels-desktop

I am currently using Windows 8.1 in parallels under Mac OS X Mavericks.
On both Mac and Windows I use US International since I need the special danish chars æ, ø and å. 
These chars are placed differently on the mac layout and the windows layout. 
This is very confusing!

Is there a way to make them the same - the mac placement is to prefer?

Comment: To get this I think you would need to find and install an already made Windows layout, most likely called "US International (Mac)" in your Windows OS, or make one yourself with the MKLC  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?265348-How-to-get-same-keyboard-layout-in-Windows-8-as-on-Mac
Basically I had to find an apple keyboard for US International and use it.